# Given integer: find odd and even numbers

Tags: c++, int

I have a code. My question would be: why don't I get `even_numbers0`,`even_numbers1`,`even_numbers2`..?
Or `odd_numbers0`, `odd_numbers1`, `odd_numbers2`, `odd_numbers3`...?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int even_numbers=0, odd_numbers=0, g=0;
    int even_numbers0=0, even_numbers1=0, even_numbers2=0, even_numbers3=0, even_numbers4=0;
    int odd_numbers0=0, odd_numbers1=0, odd_numbers2=0, odd_numbers3=0, odd_numbers4=0;
    int integer=1264;
    int integer_0, integer_1, integer_2, integer_3, integer_4;
    int array_1[5], array_2[5];  //int is from -32768 to 32768
    integer=integer%100000;


    if(integer!=0)
    {
    integer_0=integer%10000/1000;
    integer_1=integer%1000/100;
    integer_2=integer%100/10;
    integer_3=integer%10;
    integer_4=integer/100000;

    if(integer_0!=0)
    {
        cout<<"integer 0 - "<<integer_0<<endl;
        if(integer_0%2==0)
        {
            cout<<"even 0 - "<<integer_0<<endl;
            even_numbers0+=integer_0;
            even_numbers++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Odd 0 - "<<integer_0<<endl;
            odd_numbers0+=integer_0;
            odd_numbers++;
        }
    }

    if(integer_1!=0)
    {
        cout<<"integer 1 - "<<integer_1<<endl;
        if(integer_1%2==0)
        {
            cout<<"even 1 - "<<integer_1<<endl;
            even_numbers1+=integer_1;
            even_numbers++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Odd 1 - "<<integer_1<<endl;
            odd_numbers1+=integer_1;
            odd_numbers++;
        }
    }
    if(integer_2!=0)
    {
        cout<<"integer 2 - "<<integer_2<<endl;
        if(integer_2%2==0)
        {
            cout<<"even 2 - "<<integer_2<<endl;
            even_numbers2+=integer_2;
            even_numbers++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Odd 2 - "<<integer_2<<endl;
            odd_numbers2+=integer_2;
            odd_numbers++;
        }
    }
    if(integer_3!=0)
    {
        cout<<"integer 3 - "<<integer_3<<endl;
        if(integer_3%2==0)
        {
            cout<<"even 3 - "<<integer_3<<endl;
            even_numbers3+=integer_3;
            even_numbers++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Odd 3 - "<<integer_3<<endl;
            odd_numbers3+=integer_3;
            odd_numbers++;
        }
    }
    if(integer_4!=0)
    {
        cout<<"integer 4 - "<<integer_4<<endl;
        if(integer_4%2==0)
        {
            //cout<<"even 4 - "<<integer_4<<endl;
            even_numbers4+=integer_4;
            even_numbers++;
        }
        else
        {
            //cout<<"Odd 4 - "<<integer_4<<endl;
            odd_numbers4+=integer_4;
            odd_numbers++;
        }
    }

    }


   // cout<<"odd"<<odd_numbers<<endl;
    //cout<<"even"<<even_numbers<<endl;

if (even_numbers4!=0)
{
cout<<"Event 4 "<<even_numbers4<<endl;
}
else if(odd_numbers4!=0)
{cout<<"odd 4 "<<odd_numbers4<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Here I wrote:

```
 if (even_numbers4!=0)
    {
    cout<<"Event 4 "<<even_numbers4<<endl;
    }
    else if(odd_numbers4!=0)
    {cout<<"odd 4 "<<odd_numbers4<<endl;
    }
```

And it still gets `0`.

Output:

~ all the integer numbers: 1264

~ odd (1) and even (2,6,4) numbers.

~ the biggest even (6) and the smallest odd (1) numbers.

~ written the biggest number out of odd numbers (1).

~ written the smallest number out of even numbers (246).

Comment: TLDR. a) what is your question? b) http://sscce.org/

Comment: Is your `int` really 16 bits? That surprises me. Anyway, why are there so many sets of variables that look like they should be an array?

Comment: Can you please provide the program output??

Comment: Your odd/even_numbers4 probably aren't getting the numbers you want.

Comment: @SantoshSahu I did it!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do (I think) is count the number of even and odd digits in an integer.

The way you've done it is not the best method. Try this instead:

```
std::pair<int,int> count_odd_even(unsigned x) {
    int num_odd = 0;
    int num_even = 0;

    if (!x) num_even = 1;
    for(; x; x /= 10) {
        if (x & 1) num_odd++;
        else       num_even++;
    }

    return std::make_pair(num_odd, num_even);
}
```

Comment: You should try to state your problem clearly instead of dumping code. It's easy to extend what I wrote, simply create two std::vector<...> evens, odds, and push_back each digit in the if.

Comment: Can You give me an example? I am not much familiar with vectors and so as I am just a beginner...